# How to check if a record with a specific primary key exists in a MySql table from JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

How can i find out, from a Java program using JDBC if my table has a record with a specific primary key value? Can i use the `ResultSet` somehow after i issue a `SELECT` statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Count` might be a better idea for this case. You can use it like so:

```
public static int countRows(Connection conn, String tableName) throws SQLException {
    // select the number of rows in the table
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    int rowCount = -1;
    try {
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + tableName + " WHERE.... ");
      // get the number of rows from the result set
      rs.next();
      rowCount = rs.getInt(1);
    } finally {
      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
    }
    return rowCount;
  }
```

Taken from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/CountrowsinMySQL.htm).

Comment: I know this is an old post, but this doesn't even answer the question asked.

Comment: @user1377392: You are counting the amount of elements which satisfy a given condition. If the result is greater than 0, then it exists. Counting might be better because you are not returning an entire result set, thus data transmission is minimal.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like

```
private boolean hasRecord(String id) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "Select 1 from MyTable where id = ?";  

    PreparedStatement ps = dbConn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1,id);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

    return rs.next();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in four steps.

1. Write SQL. Something like `select count(1) from table where column = 34343` will do.
2. Learn how to get connection using JDBC.
3. Learn about `PreparedStatement`s in Java.
4. Learn how to read values from `ResultSet`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select case 
            when exists (select 1 
                         from table 
                         where column_ = '<value>' and rownum=1) 
            then 'Y' 
            else 'N' 
        end as rec_exists
from dual;
```

Comment: Just brilliant!!!!.Should have been accepted as an answer. Count(*) would actually take a long time, better to use this which is definitely much faster.